# How to open and edit an incorrect json file?

Tags: python, json

Maybe this question is a bit dumb but I actually don't know how to fix it. I have a json file that is in the wrong format. it has a b' before the first { and also it uses single quotes instead of double quotes which is not an accepted format for json.

I know that I have to replace the single quotes with double quotes. I would use something like this:

```
json = file.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
```

But the problem is how can I replace the quotes in the file if I can't open it?

```
import json

f = open("data/qa_Automotive.json",'r')
file = json.load(f)
```

Opening the file gives me an error because It has single quotes and not double quotes:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

How am I supposed to change the quotes in the json file if I can't open the file because it has the wrong format? (This is the json file btw: https://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/qa/qa_Appliances.json.gz)

Comment: YOU **CAN** OPEN THE FILE and you are doing so. What do you think `open` does? You'll have to do `f.read().replace("'", '"')`. Also note that your method is not efficient. There might be `'` inside of a string.

Comment: Sounds like this file has a `repr()` of a Python data structure instead of being JSON at all. If that's the case, you can parse it using `ast.literal_eval()` without needing to modify the data first.

Comment: @Daniel Please change your accepted answer to the one by Charles Duffy. [`eval` **really** is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) and should ONLY be used on completely sanitized data and ONLY if it is truly needed. Neither case applies here, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) should be used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file isn't JSON (the filename is incorrect); instead, it's composed of valid Python literals. There's no reason to try to transform it to JSON. Don't do that; instead, just tell Python to parse it as-is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ast, json

results = [ ast.literal_eval(line) for line in open('qa_Appliances.json') ]
print(json.dumps(results))
```

...properly gives you a list named `results` with all your lines in it, and (for demonstration purposes) dumps it to stdout as JSON.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issue with that file :

- it is ndjson (new line delimited, each line is a single object)
- there is a mixing of quote

First issue is easily solve, you can just load each line individually, second issue is tricker.

I tried (as you did) to simply replace `'` with `"`. But that is not enough, as there is `'` in the text (like "you're"), there is a single quote there. If you replace all the `'`, that will be transformed into a `"` and break your string.

You'll be left with something like `"message": "you"re"` which is invalid.

Since there is a lot of issue with that file, I suggest to use something a little dirty: the python `eval` function.

`eval` simply play a string as if it was a command.

```py
>>> eval("4 + 2")
6
```

Because json format, and Python native `dict` type are really close (minus some difference like Python use `True/False` and json use `true/false`. Python use `None` and json use `null`, and maybe other that I forgot), the structure with the curly and squared bracket are the same. But here, "eval" will help you because Python support both single, and double quote

Using a line from your file:

```py
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> data = "{'questionType': 'yes/no', 'asin': 'B0002Z1GG0', 'answerTime': 'Dec 10, 2013', 'unixTime': 1386662400, 'question': 'would this work on my hotpoint model ctx14ayxkrwh serial hr749157 refrigerator do the drawers slide into slots ?', 'answerType': '?', 'answer': 'the drawers do fit into the slots.'}"
>>> parsed = eval(data)
>>> print(parsed)
{'questionType': 'yes/no', 'asin': 'B0002Z1GG0', 'answerTime': 'Dec 10, 2013', 'unixTime': 1386662400, 'question': 'would this work on my hotpoint model ctx14ayxkrwh serial hr749157 refrigerator do the drawers slide into slots ?', 'answerType': '?', 'answer': 'the drawers do fit into the slots.'}
>>> type(parsed)
<class 'dict'>
>>> print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=2))
{
  "questionType": "yes/no",
  "asin": "B0002Z1GG0",
  "answerTime": "Dec 10, 2013",
  "unixTime": 1386662400,
  "question": "would this work on my hotpoint model ctx14ayxkrwh serial hr749157 refrigerator do the drawers slide into slots ?",
  "answerType": "?",
  "answer": "the drawers do fit into the slots."
}
```

I can do that on the whole file:

```py
>>> data = open("<path to file>").readlines()
>>> parsed = [ eval(line) for line in data ]
>>> 
>>> len(parsed)
9011
>>> parsed[0]
{'questionType': 'yes/no', 'asin': 'B00004U9JP', 'answerTime': 'Jun 27, 2014', 'unixTime': 1403852400, 'question': 'I have a 9 year old Badger 1 that needs replacing, will this Badger 1 install just like the original one?', 'answerType': '?', 'answer': 'I replaced my old one with this without a hitch.'}
>>> parsed[0]['questionType']
'yes/no'
```

**BEWARE** You should never use `eval` on unsanitazed data, as it can be use to breach your system, but if you use it in a controlled environment, you do you.

Comment: Also for those differences between `JSON` and `Python` you can just simply declare them as variables before using `eval`. So you would need to do `null = None` and `true = True` with `false = False`.

Comment: Oh, that is pretty creative ! I guess you should send them as `locals` (or `globals`) in the `eval` call ? Something like : `eval(data, {'null': None, 'true': True, 'false': False})` ?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` avoids the security issues that come with `eval`.

Comment: @Countour-Integral, the OP's data (if you download the file they linked to) doesn't use `null` or `true` or `false`; if such literals are needed, it _already_ uses `None`, `True` and `False` (insofar as it's already `eval`able as literals). It's not corrupt JSON at all, it's just Python literals one-per-line.

Comment: [`eval` REALLY IS DANGEROUS](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) and should ONLY be used on completely sanitized data and ONLY if it is truly needed. Neither case applies here, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) should be used instead. @CharlesDuffy's answer is the correct one.